# Would decision tree propagate error?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, consistency

Given a regression dataset $X,Y$. Suppose there are two different decision tree (CART) $T_1, T_2$ fitted from it. Each using different feature encoding method. And we get two different tree.

And there are many ways to compare them. The simplest might be have k fold cross validation.

For each tree, if we construct a “mini” tree by only using the root decision node and construct a decision stump out of it: $S_1, S_2$.

Now my question is for whatever reasonable comparing method we choose, would the outcome of $T_1$ and $T_2$ be consistent to if we apply to $S_1$ and $S_2$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Based on the feature encoding used, the root split might be better for $T_1$ but not enough for $T_2$, because the consequent levels of the tree may complement the root very well. For example, if $T_1$ uses a 1D mapping for an inherently multi dimensional feature, the first split might be very informative, especially compared to splitting a the one-hot encoded version of the same feature. So, $T_1$ may look like the better option, but if the feature is best represented on a multi dimensional setting, the following splits in the tree in $T_2$ may compensate it and can be better than the one in $T_1$.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow, as there is no mentioning of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: "The first split" I mention above is $S_i$ for $T_i$.

Comment: Hmm… right, I guess the setup is too general, what if we put constraints on $T_1$ and $T_2$, for example, both of them have maximum depth 2.

Comment: I still don’t think it can be generalized. One can find a dataset that would make different choices for DTs with different levels. This is like comparing neural nets with their first layers only.